# Rails project wont let me type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to build my first rails project with MySQL. I'm using the command line and have gotten to the point where localhost:3000 shows a "Yay! Your on Rails" message. The problem is, I cant move forward from this point. The ruby command line is almost like frozen - it won't let me type anything besides for Ctrl c (to exit). Please advise me on how to proceed!

Comment: By ruby command line, do you mean the terminal? I think you have started the rails server by using the command 'rails server'. If so, you have to leave that running while you use the site locally on your machine. However, you can open a second terminal window and execute commands there.

Comment: @KevinK Yes, I used "rails server" to start it. If I open a second terminal window, it creates a skeleton for a brand new project instead of modifying this one.

Comment: @KevinK Im using a windows computer

Comment: Maybe you should consider this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

First install a gem to use mysql

```
gem install mysql2
```

Create your app

```
rails new your_app_name -d mysql
```

Go to folder project

```
cd your_app_name
```

Create a scaffold for book with title author and isbn, to you create, edit, remove a book

```
rails g scaffold book title:string author:string isbn:string
```

Create a database for your app

```
rake db:create
```

Call migrate to create table for book on database

```
rake db:migrate
```

Start a app

```
rails s
```

Navigate to http://localhost:3000/books/new

Answer (score 0):

`rails server` (aka `rails s`) is supposed to do exactly what you describe -- continue serving pages until you hit Ctrl-C to kill the server.

You'll typically open one terminal, run `rails s`, and leave that running while you open other terminals for things like running tests, git, editing, etc. You won't spend a lot of time looking at the server window, unless you need to examine runtime errors or other diagnostic info.

Don't be afraid to have lots of terminals open. I have a baseline of four open for development (rails server, rails console, rspec/rubocop, everything else), and it's not uncommon to have 6-8 per project when things get interesting.